# Proportion for the values of maxrate, mnrate and bufsize for encoding videos for streaming purpose and past duration too large warning

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

can you please tell me about minrate, maxrate and bufsize. And is it necessary to give maxrate and minrate for encoding videos for streaming purpose. Actually I understood the meaning and functions of minrate, maxrate and bufsize through ffmpeg documents but I am not finding any solution of what would be difference in between the values of these three.

for example : I am using this command 
ffmpeg -y -i testing.mp4 -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -ab 128k -c:v libx264 -r 24 -g 24 -b:v 2m -maxrate 1m -bufsize 1m -vf scale=1920*1080 aa.mp4

but I am not sure if this -b:v 2m -maxrate 1m bufsize 1m is in correct propotions or not. My output is fine but I don't want any problem on working real time. Moreover, I am also getting the following warning

Past duration 0.634361 too large
Past duration 0.674370 too large
Past duration 0.714363 too large 0kB time=00:00:01.32 bitrate= 0.3kbits/s

Past duration 0.754372 too large
Past duration 0.794365 too large
Past duration 0.834373 too large
Past duration 0.874367 too large
Past duration 0.914360 too large
Past duration 0.954369 too large

thanks in advance

Comment: This has been answered [here on Superuser SE](http://superuser.com/q/945413).